# After updating adt , avd did not work anymore

Tags: android, adt, haxm

I just  updated ADT (it was its recommendation) my avd did not work and shows this error message:

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this Avd .  /dev/kvm in not found . 
Enable VT-x in your Bios security setting Ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module
```

First of all, I enabled VT-x long times ago so I think maybe it is disabled somehow, so checked it and it is enable yet. Secondly I use Win7 not Linux, why did it say "..Ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module." ?

My next question is what is the matter with Stackoverflow I just become member of it and ask 5 questions and get banned 2 times even in my fu.. dictatorship country I can ask more question before they shout me up. Really what is the matter with it?!

Comment: Please go into help center and get familiar with [asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Focus on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), improve quality of your questions to avoid next [ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: I don't know why you're getting banned, but here's what I do know: for years and years the moderators here on Stack Overflow have been getting many, many low-quality questions, and they're frustrated... They want people to use the site in certain ways, and many users want to use the site in other ways, especially when these users are new and don't understand the rules. If you want to get a sense of how the moderators feel, read some of these posts on Meta:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/3345375

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/3345375